# Youwave for Android in remote desktop environment using thin client

Tags: android, windows, thin-client, youwave-for-android

I am using **YouWave** for **Android** in a remote desktop environment with **Atrust Thin Client T60** series.  When I run the **YouWave** emulator, a black screen appears and it stops there.

Also the home, menu and other buttons (except rotate button) does not work. When I tried to run an app it says

> Android OS not ready.

When I open **YouWave** for a second time, it says

> Another YouWave for Android is already running or previous run is cleaning up.

This repeats even if I tried to open waiting for few minutes.  Is there any remedy for this?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but may I ask why are you using Youwave? I couldn't make it work either, so I finally decided to use bluestacks (http://www.bluestacks.com/) and it worked perfectly. The player is also free, and they can even convert your apk into an exe file for some money.

Comment: reinstalling YouWave worked for me.

Comment: @mjosh: Reinstalling did not fixed for me, still the same problem prevails.

Answer (score 1):

A better alternative to YouWave or Bluestacks is [GenyMotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)

it is the fastest emulator ive ever used, everything works 
to use it first visit the website, signup for an account then download the genymotion application. It works with Windows, Mac, Linux/Debian Linux.

After installing it, login using the signed up data & you will get a list of devices.
These are images of various physically available Android devices like nexus 7, nexus s etc. Download the desired device image.

These images are rooted & some with gapps, you can link the emulator to the android sdk for directly testing your app in the emulator. This emulator is so awesome that you can change the resolution of the device. you can add a shared folder using virtualbox, the shared folder is located @ mnt/shared/

Answer (score 0):

Try this and start again the YouWave

- Go to `Start` > `Run` (or press `Windows + R`)
- Copy and paste the bold text to the dialog box: `%USERPROFILE%\.Virtualbox\HardDisks`
- Delete or rename `youwave_vm01.vdi`
- Copy and rename `youwave_vm01_golden.vdi` to `youwave_vm01.vdi`

NOTE: `youwave_vm01_golden.vdi` is a clean Android instalation, keep a copy at all times.

Comment: I tried it, but its not working for me. The same message appears. May be it is due to the remote desktop environment, the thin client for this problem with youwave. Can not figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `BlueStacks`.
I am using it, and it's working all right, i was also having issues with YouWave.